# User-Agent in Google App Engine python

Tags: google-app-engine, browser

I'm using Google App Engine python. I want to know what browser the user is using.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
class BaseRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def browser(self):
    return str(self.request.headers['User-Agent'])
```

Comment: if webapp2 : `self.request.headers.get('User-Agent')`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Django, that should be:

```
def some_view(request)
    return HttpResponse(request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
```