# detect web browser using python and WebApp2

Tags: python, mobile, browser, desktop, webapp2

I want to know if my web browser is mobile or desktop. I am using WebApp2. How can I detect my browser? The following code is return false positives for mobile.

```
import re
...
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user_agent = get_user_agent(self.request)
        logging.warning('User agent is %s', user_agent)
        if is_desktop(user_agent):
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('path/desktop.html')
        else:
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('path/mobile.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render( {}))

# Some mobile browsers which look like desktop browsers.
RE_MOBILE = re.compile(r"(iphone|ipod|blackberry|android|palm|windows\s+ce)", re.I)
RE_DESKTOP = re.compile(r"(windows|linux|os\s+[x9]|solaris|bsd)", re.I)
RE_BOT = re.compile(r"(spider|crawl|slurp|bot)")


def is_desktop(user_agent):
    """
        Anything that looks like a phone isn't a desktop.
        Anything that looks like a desktop probably is.
        Anything that looks like a bot should default to desktop.

        """
    return not bool(RE_MOBILE.search(user_agent)) and \
        bool(RE_DESKTOP.search(user_agent)) or \
            bool(RE_BOT.search(user_agent))

def get_user_agent(request):
    # Some mobile browsers put the User-Agent in a HTTP-X header
    return request.headers.get('HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA') or \
        request.headers.get('HTTP_X_SKYFIRE_PHONE') or \
            request.headers.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '')
```

Thanks for any help. By the way, I get this code (i.e. most of it) from https://gist.github.com/johnboxall/88057

Maybe the code is working. But **the logging for user agent always returns blank**

Comment: You can get your user agent from the following. But the rest of the code may still not work for some browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309377/user-agent-in-google-app-engine-python

Comment: Thanks that worked in getting me the user again. But the code does not always work in telling me the whether it's mobile. Chrome and Safari work. But the "Internet" app/browser that comes with Galaxy S5 does not work. Also the iPad does not know it's mobile.